# how do you print a receipt using Star TSP 650 II?

Tags: python, django, printing, receipt

Does anyone know a beginner friendly tutorial for Star TSP 650II (using parallel  port) to print something from django/python?

I can't seem to figure out how it works.

Answer (score 0):

It's not an easy one, as the Star TSP printers accept 'Star graphic mode commands' - You can see the full commandset here:

http://www.starasia.com/Download/Manual/star_graphic_cm_en.pdf

I spent some time creating a python module - [StarTSPImage](https://pypi.org/project/StarTSPImage/), which will take a PIL image in Python, and then convert to the right raster/binary data that the printer is expecting. Using the module can print an image with the following:

```js
import StarTSPImage

raster = StarTSPImage.imageFileToRaster('file.bmp', cut=True))

printer = open('/dev/usb/lp0', 'wb')
printer.write(raster)
```

I have used imgkit to generate an image from HTML in the past and used that for reciepts.